# Mongodb, Django-version1.5

Tags: django, mongodb

mongodb-engine doesn't support django 1.4 at this time. so stick with 1.3.

is it true?

I am using Django1.5.

I got error "tuple does not have insert ".

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need to use django-1.3